# Disable dates with the use of radio buttons (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I would like to be able to manipulate the available dates that date picker displays according to certain radio buttons. I have 3 radio buttons

HTML

```
<div id = "date">
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "1" >bob</label>
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "2" >lucy</label>
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "3" >dan</label>
</div>
```

When bob is clicked, I would like Monday and Tuesday to be the only dates available
When Lucy is clicked, I would like Wednesday and Thursday to be the only dates available
When Dan is clicked, I would like only Friday to be available

HTML Code for datePicker

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I tried to implement this using Jquery but the problem i am facing is that when one radio button is clicked, it displays the available dates correctly but when I click another button, the dates do not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#date input:radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      $('#date').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
          var day = date.getDay()
          return [day != 0 && day != 6 && day != 5 && day != 3 && day != 4, '']
        },
      })
    } else if ($(this).val() === '2') {
      $('#date').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
          var day = date.getDay()
          return [day != 0 && day != 6 && day != 1 && day != 5 && day != 2, '']
        },
      })
    }
  })
})
```

***I did not finish the JQUERY implementation after noticing that it did not update***

Comment: are you using bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: JQUERY datepicker

Comment: Can you give the name of that library?

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

hope below will help you

HTML

```
    <div id = "date">
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "1" checked>bob</label>
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "2" >lucy</label>
<label><input type = "radio" name = "pickDate" value = "3" >dan</label>
</div>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Script

```
var pickdate = 1;

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    pickdate  = $(this).val();
});

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
      function(dt)
      { 
        if(pickdate ==1)
            return [dt.getDay() == 0 , "" ];
        else if(pickdate ==2)
            return [dt.getDay() == 1 , "" ];
        else 
            return [dt.getDay() == 2 , "" ];
      }}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crpwjtav/